# Ansible yum update a package when is it actually available

Tags: centos, ansible, yum

I am trying to write a simple ansible playbook to deal with performing yum update on servers, if the update is available, and then reboot if update was performed. I can't really figure out how to check if the package update is available without doing something crazy with shell level command. Maybe someone can give me some pointers.

```
- name: Update glibc package
  hosts: all
  user: root

  vars:
    pkg_name: glibc

  tasks:
  - name: Flag for update if available
    ??
    register: update_available

  - name: Run yum update
    yum: name={{ pkg_name }} state=latest
    when: update_available.changed
    register: run_reboot

  - include: reboot_server.yml
    when: run_reboot.changed
```

Comment: What do you need this for? Just have the yum task with `state=latest`. No need to only execute that task if an update is available.

Comment: Yea I discovered that after I did some testing on how the yum module behaves for state=latest. Documentation wasn't quite clear on its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working. The yum module worked the way I had hoped.

```
- name: Update a yum package
  hosts: all
  user: root

  vars:
    pkg_name: glibc

  tasks:

  - name: Run yum update
    yum: name={{ pkg_name }} state=latest
    register: run_reboot

  - include: reboot_server.yml
    when: run_reboot.changed
```